# booting stuck on logo please help me

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am currently trying to boot from a usb so i've never even got into the system and it freezes on this screen ive used balena etcher and rufus both gave me the same issue rufus was a little better it has happened on old windows partitions and new ones and old and new usbs I have never enter ubuntu so I assume it is a bios issue I use edge so can someone pls help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqkzf.jpg)

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip. If newer system you have to use 20.04LTS and most should use it. May be video issue, and then you need safe boot option & then install optional restricted drivers to get correct video driver installed.

Comment: After downloading the .iso file did you do a checksum?